# The word CHAPTERS: in Table of contents before appendices

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to remove the word "CHAPTERS:" that appears above the appendices listing in table of contents

a MWE is

```
\documentclass[ms]{osudissert96}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,amscd,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}%colortext
\usepackage{longtable}% Using longtable environment
\usepackage{ifthen}% Gives \ifthenelse
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}% Define the path to the figures colorlinks,
\usepackage[]{mcode}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{booktabs}


% Fix referencing of nested enumerations (put a dot between counters)
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumi.\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{\theenumi.}
\makeatother


\makeatletter \@addtoreset{footnote}{chapter} \makeatother % Clear the footnote counter at every new chapter

% The following adds the hyperlinks and makes the page navigator in the pdf viewer cool
\usepackage[breaklinks, hyperindex,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

% This will make chapter titles show up in uppercase (however, they will be normal case in the TOC)
\renewcommand\typesetChapterTitle[1]{\uppercase{#1}}

% Notation:
%\def\listofnotation{\input symbols.tex \clearpage}
%\def\addnotation #1 #2#3{#1\> \parbox{5in}{#2 \dotfill  \pageref{#3}}\\}
%\def\newnot#1{\label{#1}}





%% To speed up compilation, you can comment all commands that include chapters you're interested in till you finish each chapter separately, or use the includeonly command
%\includeonly{ch1-intro}

\include{commands}


\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage


\chapter{CH1}

\renewcommand\pagenumbering[1]{}
\begin{appendices}

\chapter{MATLAB Code}\label{App:Matlab_Code}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the specific question, but if [this page](http://phaseportrait.blogspot.com/2011/02/updated-latex-document-class-for-ohio.html) is accurate, the 1996 dissertation class you're using is out of compliance at OSU.

Comment: Does the answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 4):

I've downloaded the following files to be able to compile your MWE:

1. http://www2.ece.ohio-state.edu/ips/home/resources/osudissert96.cls
2. http://www2.ece.ohio-state.edu/ips/home/resources/osudissert96-mods.sty
3. http://web.mit.edu/~paul_s/www/14.170/matlab/mcode.sty

The problem is in the definition of `\@chapter` in the file `osudissert96-mods.sty`.

It can be solved adding the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}

  \ifapp
  \else
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=1
      \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \fi
  \fi
  \pagestyle{headings}

  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter.}#1}%
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
  \fi

  \chaptermark{#1}%

  \if@twocolumn
     \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
  \else
     \@makechapterhead{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I'd remove the blank lines in the definition

Comment: @egreg They are in the original file, so probably they are supposed to be there.