# Changing Font and Make Header for a Thesis

Tags: fonts

I want to set the font to 14pt in my Master Thesis, and make a header contains the following:

> Chapter#                                             chapter Name

I use a style file and a a .cls one.

I have asked another question in :
[The word CHAPTERS: in Table of contents before appendices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165089/the-word-chapters-in-table-of-contents-before-appendices?noredirect=1#comment379267_165089)

The answer there may help with this one.

A MWE is as follows

```
\documentclass[ms]{osudissert96}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,amscd,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}%colortext
\usepackage{longtable}% Using longtable environment
\usepackage{ifthen}% Gives \ifthenelse
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}% Define the path to the figures colorlinks,
\usepackage[]{mcode}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{booktabs}


% Fix referencing of nested enumerations (put a dot between counters)
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumi.\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{\theenumi.}
\makeatother


\makeatletter \@addtoreset{footnote}{chapter} \makeatother % Clear the footnote counter at every new chapter

% The following adds the hyperlinks and makes the page navigator in the pdf viewer cool
\usepackage[breaklinks, hyperindex,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

% This will make chapter titles show up in uppercase (however, they will be normal case in the TOC)
\renewcommand\typesetChapterTitle[1]{\uppercase{#1}}

% Notation:
%\def\listofnotation{\input symbols.tex \clearpage}
%\def\addnotation #1 #2#3{#1\> \parbox{5in}{#2 \dotfill  \pageref{#3}}\\}
%\def\newnot#1{\label{#1}}





%% To speed up compilation, you can comment all commands that include chapters you're interested in till you finish each chapter separately, or use the includeonly command
%\includeonly{ch1-intro}

\include{commands}


\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage


\chapter{CH1}

\renewcommand\pagenumbering[1]{}
\begin{appendices}

\chapter{MATLAB Code}\label{App:Matlab_Code}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you solved this one or are you still looking for answers?